# Django group by foreign key id

Tags: django

How can I group a query `Qualifications` and group them by `quote__uuid`? I looked into [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) but doesn't seem to fit my need.

My ideal output is `[{'quote_uuid_1':[qualification_1, qualification_2], 'quote_uuid_2':[qualification_3] }]`

```
class Quote
   uuid = models.CharField()

class Qualification
   quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote)
```

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: Note that your ideal output is invalid. A dictionary cannot have the same key more than once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
result = [{quote.id:quote.qualification_set.all()} for quote in Quote.objects.all()]
```